# EF tables with Many to many relationship, Will this consume memory?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have 2 tables that saved family members, when I use `include` to retrieve the family members, the generated T-SQL is what I'm expected, but when I see the result from VS, like image below, it's look like never ending.

My questions:

1. It's this normal?
2. Should I avoid `include` when the relationship becomes complex?
3. If it is normal, will this very memory consumption?

POCO

```
public  class Cust_ProfileTbl
{
    [Key]
    public long bintAccountNo { get; set; } 
    public string nvarCardName { get; set; }
    public string varEmail { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl> profileFamilyParents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl> profileFamilyChildren { get; set; }
}

public class Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl
{
    [Key]
    public int intProfileFamily { get; set; } 
    public long bintAccountNo { get; set; }
    public long bintAccountNoMember { get; set; }

    public virtual Cust_ProfileTbl custProfileParent { get; set; }
    public virtual Cust_ProfileTbl custProfileChild { get; set; }
}
```

LINQ

```
var rs = from family in context.member.Include("profileFamilyParents.custProfileChild")
         select family;

rs = rs.Where(x => x.bintAccountNo.Equals(1));

var result = rs.ToList();
```

In onModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl>()
       .HasRequired(m => m.custProfileParent)
       .WithMany(t => t.profileFamilyParents)
       .HasForeignKey(m => m.bintAccountNo)
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.custProfileChild)
            .WithMany(t => t.profileFamilyChildren)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.bintAccountNoMember)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

[image: Result when mouse hover]

Comment: Your question is strange... If there are no families in the DB it will consume nearly no memory. If there are billions of families in the DB the server will run out of memory. If there a few families, it seems fine... Why you think that relations are complex? Why wouldn't you use include?

Comment: @JotaBe Sorry, if the question confuse:). The reason i said complex when this particular user involve in other transaction, like for example if the user had perform transaction in purchase table, and his  id (bintAccountNo) will appear in purchase table and if i use include all related entities will retrieve include the family member and their name which i don't even need it. So is there a way to use "include" which could stop retrieve the related entities in this case the family member.

Comment: I think you need to re-state your quesion. However, the only way to bring only the information that you need is by pojecting it with `Select` into a new anonymous, or existent class. If you do so, you lose the change tracking. (But, if you only use the data for reading, that doesn't matter). The way to do it is `query.Select(i => new { a = i.a, b = i.b, ... })`

Comment: I bet the debugger is just lazy loading them as you walk through the tree, not all that data gets loaded normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When people use an ORM like EF in their application, many times the application design gets driven by this ORM and the entities defined in its model. When the app is a simple "CRUD" application, that's not a problem, but an advantage, because you spare a lot of time.

However when things start to get more complicated, an "ORM guided design" becomes a problem. This looks to be the case.

There are at least two problems, recovered from the comments:

1. the data retrieved from the DB is more than needed
2. in this case, because of some particular relationships between entities, there is a circular reference, which creates an endless loop and a stack overflow when trying to show the model in the view

When this kind of situation shows up, the most advisable is to break the tight tie between the ORM and the rest of the app, which can be dine by defining a new class, and projecting the data into it. Let's give a generic `ProfileDto` name.

```
public class ProfileDto { ... }
```

*DTO is a generic name for this kind of classes: Data Transfer Objects - but, when they have specific purposes, they can get other names like view models, when they're going to be used as the model sent to an MVC view*

And then, what you need to do is to project the result of the query into the DTO:

```
var model = theQuery.Select(i => new ProfileDto { a = i.a, b = i.b...}).ToList();
```

With a good design of the Dto you'll only recover the needed data from the DB, and you'll avoid the loop problem (by not including the navigation property that creates the loop).

*NOTE: many times people uses mappers, like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) or [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) to make the mapping, or part of the mapping, automatic*

Code standardization is a very good idea until it becomes a source of problems. The main purpose of writing code is implementing the business logic. If code standardization, technology, or whatever, makes it harder to implement business logic, instead of contributing to the solution, they become a problem, so you need to avoid them.

Comment: Not sure how true is this, the endles loop result is actually a magic of EF, which i think that will cause to consume a lot of memory. Which i not really like it. :).

Comment: Just one more question, if you code in this way var model = theQuery.Select(i => new ProfileDto { a = i.a, b = i.b...}).ToList();, why do you still need mapper? I kind of confuse, Dto same with viewmodels?

Answer (score 1):

1. Mapping you created is Normal but use of Include depends upon its usage
2. Use of Include depends on situation of use for example if you want to cache it in memory then you may use include, Where as if you are using only showing properties of Cust_ProfileTbl
   class in some grid and on click you want show details of Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl then you might don't want to use include. But be careful if you are using Automapper or something because when It will try to map related properties it will query database.
3. It will consume memeory when you execute ToList() as doing so you are Loading query result into List collection. Where as If you again want to query the result then you can use ToQueryable() or just want to iterate the you can don't load them to List.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. 1. Even in VS we saw the endless results is considered normal? 2. The reason we use "Include" is because we want to standardize the coding method when retrieve data by id. So all of us use the same method to retrieve but when we see the result it's seem like not a good idea to retrieve in this way, as it will retrieve non-necessary tables's data when we specify navigation properties for that table. Beside, i have another issue when the endless result map into viewmodel, it's throw "stackoverflow" error, which i not sure why and not sure how i have to ask :).

Comment: The stack over flow problem is beacuse there are circular reference (a table is parent and child at the same time, so that you enter an endless loop)